# Paths must precede expression Linux find

Tags: linux, shell, path, find, wildcard

I have the following command:

```
find -xtype f -iname '*NEN*' -o '*1990*'
```

I get the error "find: paths must precede expression: *1990*"
Why is this? I have quoted the wildcard, so I don't see the error. How to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to repeat the `-iname` argument:

```
find -xtype f -iname '*NEN*' -o -iname '*1990*'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I would never have thought about that!